# Python assigning copies of the object to variables

Tags: python

Not a technical question, just a matter of coding style.

To me it makes more sense for assigning the same value to variables syntax to be a, b = 0, rather than a, b = 0, 0, but it is what it is. At least you can go around it by doing a = b = 0 if object is a number or a string, but today I came in situation that I needed 10 identical lists. So I went like: 
list1, list2... = big_list[:], big_list[:]....

So big and ugly. How would you do it more in accordance with do-not-repeat-yourself principle?

Comment: You should probably use a dictionary in that case.

Comment: Perhaps if you can elaborate on this situation we could suggest an alternative?

Comment: Rather than having ten lists named `list1` through `list10`, I suggest creating a single list `lists`, which has ten elements.

Comment: if list1/2/3... has unique logic name, then give them unique name maybe seems tedious, but it'll improve the maintainability of your code. otherwise, you can just put them in a bigger list, and access each by index. If given the assuption  that big_list is some outsider data that you cannot change, and you have to repeat list1/2/3... at many place, then put it into a method or even class may make more sense on both code style/business logic side.

Answer (score 4):

You *could* do the following:

```
list1, list2, list3 = (big_list[:] for _ in range(3))
```

Whether that's an improvement is debatable. If you need many parallel lists, perhaps you should keep them in a collection instead of separate variables?

Comment: An alternative: `lists = [big_list[:] for _ in range(10)]`.  Then we have `lists[0]` through `lists[9]`.

Comment: Yeah, it works the way cdhowie proposed, otherwise I get a TypeError message. I could make a list of lists as others suggested, but it gets a bit complicated later on.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use a dictionary comprehension like

```
listdict = { key: value for key, value in range(1, 11), [big_list[:] for x in range(10)] }
```

Which would give you a dictionary containing the lists for reference under using keys 1 through 10 (i.e. listdict[1], listdict[2] ...etc)

Comment: If the keys are natural numbers, why not just use a list?

Comment: Of course you could, just my personal preference to stick to dictionaries in case the dataset gets so large speed becomes an issue

Comment: I am sorry, but that argument does not hold water (lists in CPython are essentially arrays, so for this use case they are likely to be faster than dictionaries).